# how to load mysql query to chartjs with php?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, mysqli, chart.js

i need help, would you guys to help me.
this my problem. i have 2 file that's:

1. main.js
2. index.php

this is the source of **main.js**:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("percent-chart2").getContext("2d");
if (ctx) {
  ctx.height = 209;
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "My First dataset",
          data: [<?php while ($p = mysqli_fetch_array($jumlah)) { echo '"' . $p['jumlah'] . '",';}?>],
          backgroundColor: [
            '#fa4251',
            '#00b5e9'
          ],
          hoverBackgroundColor: [
            '#fa4251',
            '#00b5e9'
          ],
          borderWidth: [
            0, 0
          ],
          hoverBorderColor: [
            'transparent',
            'transparent'
          ]
        }
      ],
      labels:
      [
       <?php while ($p = mysqli_fetch_array($severity)) { echo '"' . $p['severity'] . '",';}?>
      ]
    }
```

and this is the **index.php** :

```
<?php
$koneksi = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "waf", "waf");
$severity = mysqli_query($koneksi, "SELECT severity FROM severity order by severity asc");
$jumlah = mysqli_query($koneksi, "SELECT jumlah FROM severity order by severity asc");
?>
```

if i run the query from mysql the output that i get:

```
mysql> SELECT severity FROM severity order by severity asc;
+----------+
| severity |
+----------+
| CRITICAL |
| WARNING  |
+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and,

```
mysql> SELECT jumlah FROM severity order by severity asc;
+--------+
| jumlah |
+--------+
|     35 |
|     35 |
+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

when i run the php, nothing happen or appear, just blank page. what should i do ? (-_-")

another question, can i run query mysql from js ?

thanks..

Comment: `data: [<?php while ($p = mysqli_fetch_array($jumlah)) { echo '"' . $p['jumlah'] . '",';}?>]` this PHP code will not generate a valid array

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death (“just blank page”)

Answer (score 0):

It is better you first set the value of $p array in a javascript array in index.php and then use it in main.js.
for instance:

```
<script>
    var fields= [<?php  while ($p = mysqli_fetch_array($jumlah)) { echo '"' . $p['jumlah'] . '",';} ?>];
</script>
<?php
$koneksi = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "waf", "waf");
$severity = mysqli_query($koneksi, "SELECT severity FROM severity order by severity asc");
$jumlah = mysqli_query($koneksi, "SELECT jumlah FROM severity order by severity asc");
?>
```

main.js

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("percent-chart2").getContext("2d");
if (ctx) {
  ctx.height = 209;
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "My First dataset",
          data: fields,
          backgroundColor: [
            '#fa4251',
            '#00b5e9'
          ],
          hoverBackgroundColor: [
            '#fa4251',
            '#00b5e9'
          ],
          borderWidth: [
            0, 0
          ],
          hoverBorderColor: [
            'transparent',
            'transparent'
          ]
        }
      ],
      labels:
      [
       <?php while ($p = mysqli_fetch_array($severity)) { echo '"' . $p['severity'] . '",';}?>
      ]
    }
```

notice: main.js files must be called after indx.php